# I incorrectly rejected some edits, what to do?

Tags: discussion

The first edit I rejected had changed the FAQ links in my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150260/464581) to refer to ISO CPP site instead of the original C++ FAQ.

I mistakenly thought that was a too enthusiastic but uninformed user inadvertently vandalizing my answer, and so I reject not just that but also the next edit that popped up (about apparently the same), and so on.

However as it turns out the ISO CPP FAQ is based on the original, with the help of Marshall Cline and e.g. Andrei Alexandrescu, and even contains a broken link to my old correct C++ tutorial, just as in the original FAQ. Apparently Marshall has okayed moving the FAQ from his website to ISO CPP. With Usenet more or less dead there is no more question of real updates to the FAQ resulting from community discussions, so referring to ISO CPP is in my opinion now correct and I should not have rejected the updates. Can I undo the rejections? I am not sure what all answers I rejected updates for.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the only way to make it right is to manually apply the edit yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the dup suggestions, via that I found (http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5299/i-accidentally-rejected-a-suggested-edit-that-should-have-been-approved-what-do)